# How to handle Back Key in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like handle back key in my module.
Suppose  [1],[2],[3] which is in Main Fragment {A} is fragment button in one activity.in that [1],[2],[3] are sub fragment.

[1] is  paremt Fragment in that [1][i] is nested Fragment & [1][i(a)] is another nested fragment .
when i used method addBackStack() method it goes back.

But I goes from i(a) to [2] fragment & goes to [2[i]] 's nested fragment when i pressed back key it goes back to [2[i]] --> [2] --> [i(a)] -->[i] -->[1]

But user want  when Parent Fragment is [2] then [2[i]] --> [2] only

&

when Parent fragment is [1] then [i(a)] -->[i] -->[1] only

Answer (score 0):

[1][2][3]

When ever you are going to open a new fragment, clear the fragment backstack like so:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: ,I used this way but it gives error about no view Id find